# Comment after #else preprocessor directive

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, c-preprocessor

This is simple piece of C code and to my surprise it compiles successfully (at least in Visual Studio 2012 which I am using)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYCONSTANT

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    #ifdef MYCONSTANT // We can write anything here as comment
        printf("MYCONSTANT is defined");
    #else We can write any random words here without marking it as comment
        printf("MYCONSTANT is not defined");
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Question: Is writing anything after `#else` allowed this way?

Comment: Allowed? No. But http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note169 is stating *.. a preprocessing token shall not follow a #else or #endif directive before the terminating new-line character..* - so the implementation chose to simply ignore anything after it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Footnotes in the C standard are non-normative; what controls here is the [syntax rules in 6.10p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10p1), where `else-group` and `endif-line` do not allow any tokens between the `else` or `endif` and the subsequent new-line. (Comments are not tokens.) Section [5.1.1.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.3) requires violations of syntax rules to be diagnosed. Therefore a compiler that _silently_ ignores tokens on a line after `#else` or `#endif` is nonconformant.

Comment: The non-conformance of preprocessing in Visual Studio is well-documented and goes much deeper than this example. Although recent editions are getting better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In standard C, you are *not* allowed to put anything except comments on the line after `#else` or `#endif`. With the compiler on my computer, I get a warning from your code by default:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:11: warning: extra tokens at end of #else directive [-Wendif-labels]
     #else We can write any random words here without marking it as comment
           ^~
```

and this becomes a hard error if I request strict conformance with C99.

However, the original "K&R" C preprocessor *did* allow arbitrary text to appear on the line after `#else` and `#endif`, and old programs would use that.  Your compiler is being backward-compatible and allowing those old programs to compile without error.

Many C compilers allow lots of things that are nowadays considered bad style or outright wrong, by default, for the sake of allowing old code to keep working.  Look through the manual for Visual Studio and see if there is a recommended configuration to use for new programs.  I don't use VS myself so I can't give any more specific advice.